# Google Plus or Facebook Like Card UI with twitter bootstrap 2.3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The card design approach utilized by Google Plus or Facebook is great. How can I do so using twitter bootstrap 2.3 (can't use 3) where I do not want my card size and content to stay sane for a responsive design? I mean, I want the re-sizing to of a card based on the screen size and the content on it stay acceptable. Sorry for the fuzzy question. I am not sure how to be best ask what I have in my head.

Any website you may that that has card ui desing and using bootstrap?

Is there any framework that help with Card UI for desktop web application in general?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found this the other week and it's exactly what you want:

[Bootplus](http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/index.html) - Sleek, intuitive, and powerful Google styled front-end framework for faster and easier web development (Based on bootstrap)

The particular section you want is under [Plus](http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/plus.html).

So just take the styles you need and you're good to go.

Comment: it uses less. is there any other way to do it using scss and bootstrap3 ?

Comment: @vipin8169 if you look at albertpeiro's answer - the latest version oft that is for version 3 and uses scss.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I didn't want a fully fledged framework as I tend to like more the componental way of adding features, since modern web times...

Bootcards does just Cards in three flavors (Android, iOS, Desktop).
http://bootcards.org/index.html

A great addition to Bootstrap and supports bower which was just perfect as a simple command and a couple of lines got me set up.

This has the obvious advantage of decoupling framework core from fancy cards.

Moreover its style is not shouting Google Plus all over like bootplus, which is great to give it a genuine touch.

Just another option ;) hope it helps someone